# how to install dBase on cpanel/whm with php version 5.3.2

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, dbase

how can i install dBase on cpanel/whm with php version 5.3.2, i didn't see the option on EasyApache (Apache Update)

**UPDATE**
Below is the ssh command to make it work

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/dbase-5.0.1.tgz
tar -xzf dbase-5.0.1.tgz
cd dbase-5.0.1
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `dBase`?

Comment: dbase is an old database format that was popular back before mysql and others took toof in popularity. At one time it was the greatest thing ever. Now it's a relic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to response from cPanel:

> It appears Dbase is no longer available in PHP 5.3.x, I selected 5.2.13 (without building) and it showed up in the options list.

So, I switched back to php 5.2.X and installed dBase from EasyApache and it's now working.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not a lot of help for cpanel use, but if you can use pecl, dbase was moved to pecl in 5.3. You can still use it with 5.3 by doing:

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/get/dbase
```

Then add dbase.so to php.ini if it is not there already. The --enable-dbase configure option when building php does nothing in 5.3.

Comment: invalid package name/package file "channel://pecl.php.net/get/dbase"

Comment: `sudo pecl install dbase` worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Needed to install php-pear and php5-dev packages first: `sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev`

Answer (score 0):

In WHM, go to `Software > Module Installers` then click in `Manage` in PHP PECL line. `Search for "dbase" > Install`!

CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 kvm – cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 36)